# Working on more than one image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, for-loop, image-processing, imread

I started to learn Matlab newly. I am trying to learn about classification. I will make classification for my 23 images. In my function file I am using

```
I = imread('img.jpg');
a = rgb2gray(I);
bw = double(imread('mask_img.jpg'))/255;
b = rgb2gray(bw);
bwi = 1-b;
```

And working on the original image and ground truth of the image. I can handle one image and I have loop in the my main file.

```
for i=1:original_images_db.Count
    original = original_images_db.ImageLocation(i);
    groundtruth = original_file;
    [x,y] = calculateFeatures(original, groundtruth, parameters);
dataset.HorizonFeats{i} = features; 
end
```

And i related original_images_db with imageset to files. When i run my main file, naturally everytime it reads img from function file but actually in command file main can detect other images. My question is how can i make a loop in my function file so my data can be in all other images?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not at all clear, I cannot understand your last paragraph. However the variable `features` is not assigned in the loop and you do nothing with the `x` and `y` outputs, so that code is unlikely to do anything useful.

Comment: Because I did not put the all code.

Answer (score 0):

```
fname={'1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg'};
```

create cell like that, it contains all  file-path of images

```
for i=1: length(fname)
  im= imread(fname{i});  
end
```

and now you can iterate the all images

or

use dir(image_path) function

```
fnames = dir('image_directory_path');
```